# useEffect fetch not retrieving data from local db.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to mock a Plant API by using a db.json file (relative path: src\plant-api\db.json), and passing it from the parent component (`ItemList`) to its child (`Item`) but its not working because I see no data displayed on screen even though I can see it in my `console.log`.
Here's the full code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Item from "./Item";
import Data from "../plant-api/db.json"

const ItemList = () => {
  const [plants, setPlants] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(Data)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPlants(data));
  }, []);

  console.log(Data)

  return (
    <div className="items">
      {plants.map((plant) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Item data={plant} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

```
import React from "react";
import ItemCount from "./ItemCount";

const Item = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="item">
        <img src={data.pic} alt="plant-image" />
        <h3>{data.name}</h3>
        <p>{data.category}</p>
        <h4>{data.price}</h4>
        <ItemCount stock="10" initial="0" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

[image: directory structure]

Any help is needed and appreciated!

Comment: What makes the db.json a promise ? It isn't so you whether use the JSON directly or create your own promises that will resolve into JSON which will be translated into your mocked data, or better search on google for how to create a mock API using React.

Comment: Webpack imports JSON files as parsed JSON content. It does not provide a URL to use in `fetch` unless you've changed your loader configuration

Comment: Agreed, seems you should able to set the initial state directly, i.e. `useState(Data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch is used to make network calls, but since you have already have Data imported, you can just set the data in your useEffect hook: `setPlants(Data);` This should be enough if you're just trying to see how the data renders.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use the json-server package, so you can create a dummy API,.

an example of using code like the one below in the terminal, make sure the code is run in the db.json file directory.

npx json-server db.json -p2000

later there will be a json server running as an API on port 2000

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already in JSON format, you don't need to use a fetch, you can just pop it straight into the const [plants, setPlants] = useState(Data).

If you're trying to simulate a live API, you will have to create a dummy API as Dedi mentioned.